# Is there a way to add taxonomy terms to a node based on the values of an Entity Reference field?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, entities

Title says it all.  I have a content type that is using entity reference for taxonomy terms + entity connect to allow users to create new references on the fly.  I am wondering how I can read the term values (id's?) from the entity reference field, and programmatically add the corresponding terms to the node.  The terms would not be displayed, but rather linked to via the result of the entity reference field.

I'm thinking it would be possible to hook into node_save and read the values of the entity reference field, then programatically add the corresponding tags to the node.  But that said, I am unsure where to start.

Comment: Do you want the system to react to the creation of a entity reference by adding a tag to the referenced entity?

Comment: Yes, thats it, or rather more like when a taxonomy term is referenced on a node using entityreference, react and add that as a tag to the content.  I know its silly to replace term reference with entity reference, but I have a need to use entityconnect module b/c of additional fields added to taxonomy terms.